# issue with installing java package on ec2

Tags: java, ubuntu, amazon-ec2

I was trying to install java using the following command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-fonts
```

during the installation for some reason my micro-instance in EC2 kept on freezing, I guess I am not the only one having this issue as it's posted on the [aws forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=269961񁺉) as well. Now when I try to do the whole thing again I get:

```
E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.
```

However, when I try to run sudo dpkg --configure -a, it is just stuck in here:

```
Setting up sun-java6-bin (6.26-1lucid1) ...
```

for about an hour or so... WHat should I do now to get java in place?

Comment: This is not a programming question, it doesn't belong on this site. http://serverfault.com

Answer (score 1):

It could be that the repository you added doesn't have the 'right' version of java6, personally I would use canonical's repository.

First I would try to uninstall the packages and repo

```
sudo apt-get remove sun-java6-jre sun-java6-plugin sun-java6-fonts
sudo remove-apt-repository ppa:ferramroberto/java
```

And then use canonical's aptitude repository.

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb http://archive.canonical.com/ lucid partner"
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-jdk
```

Comment: Running these commands on a new EC2 instance yielded: Package sun-java6-jdk is not available, but is referred to by another package.

Comment: Canonical has removed sun-java6-jdk from its partner repository [link](http://developers.slashdot.org/story/11/12/18/1425230/canonical-to-remove-sun-java-from-repositories-users-machines)

Comment: Thanks for the link Peter... what a load of non-sense from Oracle :S

Answer (score 0):

I thinks its the same Bug: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/634487

Answer (score 0):

issue fix
**E: dpkg was interrupted, you must manually run 'sudo dpkg --configure -a' to correct the problem.**

> pd@admin:~$ **sudo dpkg --configure -a** 
>   dpkg: error: parsing file **'*/var/lib/dpkg/updates/0024*'** near line 0:  newline in field name `#padding'

pd@admin:~$ **sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/updates/0024**

pd@admin:~$ **sudo dpkg --configure -a**

pd@admin:~$ **sudo apt-get install appname_mention_here**

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done

**Now its working the installation....!**

Answer (score 0):

Simply use Open JDK like so...

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jre-headless
```

since you can only ssh into anyway... :)